# Body.ScrollTop returns 0 in Safari when body is the scrolling element rather than html

Tags: safari, scrolltop, document-body

In this example:

- HTML is set to `overflow:hidden` with a `100vh`
- Body is also set to `100vh` with `overflow` set to `scroll`

This makes body the scrolling element and there are various other reasons why this was necessary of this project.

In Chrome `document.body.scrollTop` will determine the current body scroll position but in Safari this returns as `0`.

Every other workaround also returns `0` including:

```
var scrollingElement = document.scrollingElement || document.documentElement;
console.log(scrollingElement.scrollTop)
```

and

```
window.pageYOffset
```

document.scrollingElement returns HTML BODY.

What is the problem here?

Comment: Same issue I had also facing....